# How to insert HTML text to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery. What am I doing wrong here? It will create window but not insert text. Thank you for your help

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button7').click(function(){
        $('#page').append('<div id="window"></div>');
            $("#window").load("pages/window1.html");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="window1">
    <p style="color: white">HELLO WORLD!</p>
</div>
```

next problem is that it dont want to load html file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.button7').click(function() {
     $('#page').append('<div id="window">NEW DIV ADDED</div>');
     $("#page").find("div").on("ondivload", function() {
       $("#window").load("window1.html", function() {
         alert("now external html loaded");
       });
     });
     alert("now div#window appended");
     $("#page").find("div").trigger("ondivload");

   });

 });
```

Comment: is the html in the file you specified?

Comment: think you may got your url incorrectly (you might be missing a trailing slash or need to provide full url), play with it and you'll see...

Comment: are you referring to the text `HELLO WORLD!` or the page `pages/window1.html` ? You set the color of the text `HELLO WORLD!` to white, maybe that's why you can't see the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.html()` and `.text()` to insert html and text content respectively to target control/element. And also you can use `.load()` to get content of external html file to control.- Note: this will be a `GET` request to external file and it has callback convention.

`.html` and `load` example. Click `html` to append a `div` with id = `window` and after appending , it will load html into that div window.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function() {

     $('.page').append('<div id="window">NEW DIV ADDED</div>');
     $(".page").find("div").on("ondivload", function() {
       $("#window").load("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html", function() {
         alert("now external html loaded");
       });
     });
     alert("now div#window appended");
     $(".page").find("div").trigger("ondivload");

   });

 });
```

```css
 .page {
   border: 5px #CCC solid;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="HTML" id="btn" />
<div class="page">
  OLD Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `.html()` method which get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of  elements.

If you want to insert just text you can use the function [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: apparently the op has it on an external page, not the same as where the jQuery call is made, don't think `html` or `text` would work in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You have this: `<p style="color: white">HELLO WORLD!</p>`

Unless your background color is not `white`, change the `color` to any color other than `white` if you want to see the text. `color` is to change text color.

Also, you've not added `.button7` and `#page` to the HTML

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z40zy7xx/2/)**